# Php if elseif loop is not working fine

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have below php code . It's not working. Either it just checks with if condition . If it doesn't find in If then it jumps directly to else part and print Neutral.

In my below code. I declared three arrays . One array with negative words , second with suggestion words and third array with negative words. Then i take a string and one by one checks if that string/text has negative word. If yes then print negative , otherwise check in suggestion word array. If find any suggestion word in text then print suggestion. If doesn't find suggestion word then go to positive array and search in it and so on...

In my below code , it should print "positve" but it is printing "neutral"

```
<?php

$neg_words= array('not good',
'poor',
'late',
'wrong');


$sug_words=array('would',
'should',
'suggestion',
'want');

$pos_words=array('Great',
'great',
'good',
'smile',
'pleasant',
'interesting',
'pleasing',
'nice',
'happy',
'love',
'like',
'loving',
'liking',
'amazing');

$string = 'I like the way';

$tmp =explode(' ', $string);

$strings=end($tmp);




if (in_array($strings,$neg_words)):
echo "Negative"; 
elseif (in_array($strings,$sug_words)):
 echo "Suggestion"; 
elseif (in_array($strings,$pos_words)):
echo "positive";
else:
 echo "Neutral"; 

endif;



?>
```

Comment: Why do you expect "positive"? `"way"` isn't in any of your arrays.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569). In summary, asking us to hurry up makes it even _less likely_ that you get a (good) answer.

Comment: @Peter it has "like" which is in positive.

Comment: Got it @AdrianW . Thanks for sharing (y) Will avoid using ASAP or such phrases now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues in the above code, There is no need of end().

```
<?php

$neg_words= array('not good',
'poor',
'late',
'wrong');

$sug_words=array('would',
'should',
'suggestion',
'want');

$pos_words=array('Great',
'great',
'good',
'smile',
'pleasant',
'interesting',
'pleasing',
'nice',
'happy',
'love',
'like',
'loving',
'liking',
'amazing');

$string = 'I like the way';

$strings =explode(' ', $string);





if (array_intersect($strings,$neg_words))
echo "Negative"; 
elseif (array_intersect($strings,$sug_words))
 echo "Suggestion"; 
elseif (array_intersect($strings,$pos_words))
echo "positive";
else
 echo "Neutral"; 




?>
```

Comment: "_2. in_array() works for string, array_" Not quite true, `in_array()` also works for array, array

Comment: @abhishek  Perfect ! Thank you so much for such an amazing and quick help. It worked. You are awesome ! Many thanks.

Comment: @user3196663 great!!

Comment: @user3196663 If this answer helped you solve your problem you might want to consider accepting it as an answer for your question and "rewarding" Abhishek for his work.

Comment: Thank you for reminder. I tried to do that immediately . But site showed message that i can do it in 4 minutes. I think it doesn't allow to mark it immediately. After that i got busy in work :) Thanks for reminder :)